# Android installation is looking for classes in the wrong place

Tags: gluon-mobile

In order to troubleshoot a bigger problem I created a sample app on which I can test where the problem(s) is. The code is basically the same as the one generated by the single view wizard.

When I launch it on desktop via `appliaction > run` it works fine. When I run it from my device via `other > androidInstall` I get a black screen (I also ran `clean` beforehand). So I launched `adb logcat` and found this error:

> E DalvikLauncher: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "com.gluonapplication.GluonApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.gluonapplication-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.gluonapplication-1/lib/arm,
>   /data/app/com.gluonapplication-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi, /vendor/lib,
>   /system/lib]]

which is no surprise because there is no class there. The main class is at `main.GluonApplication` (bad package name maybe but it's the test app). The `build.gradle` specifically specifies `mainClassName = 'main.GluonApplication'`. So why is the Android version looking somewhere else? Is there a manifest I need to edit/recreate? Is there some sort of caching done somewhere where previous versions of the app might reside and affect current version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you use the IDE plugin to create a project, there is a default manifest `AndroidManifest.xml`,  added to the `src/android/` folder.

If you open it, you will find the package name assigned, that will match the package of the main class, and its full name.

According to what you find on your log, this will be your current manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
          package="com.gluonapplication" 
          android:versionCode="1" 
          android:versionName="1.0">
        <supports-screens android:xlargeScreens="true"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
        <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" android:targetSdkVersion="21"/>
        <application android:label="GluonApplication" android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
                <activity android:name="javafxports.android.FXActivity" android:label="GoNative" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
                        <meta-data android:name="main.class" android:value="com.gluonapplication.GluonApplication"/>
                        <meta-data android:name="debug.port" android:value="0"/>
                        <intent-filter>
                                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
                        </intent-filter>
                </activity>
        </application>
</manifest>
```

Just make sure that the package name matches the real one, or else make the necessary changes.

Also notice that on Android you need at least two words and a dot for a valid package name, like `com.gluonapplication`.

Comment: Huh, so what are the mix and target SDK versions are for if I specify it in the gradle file? And can the manifest not be updated automatically from the gradle file with the package and versions info?

Comment: About the package name: I just changed the manifest `package` and `android:value` to my `main.GluonApplication` and it worked. So when you say "at least 2 words" you mean package.subPackage.Class or is package.Class enough?

Comment: The package name is used for unique identification for your application in Google Play, and it is recommended to use reversed domain names, that require at least two segments/words.

Comment: About your first comment, once you have a default manifest, this won't be edited from the build file, so you have to edit it yourself. If you remove that manifest, then a new one will be created and it will include the values in the build file.